Symmetric matrix $LDL$ decomposition and Sylvester's law of inertia
I am trying to figure out whether I could use Sylvester's law of inertia along with $LDL$ decomposition to figure out if a symmetric matrix is positive definite. So, let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{(n\times n)}$ be a symmetric real matrix. Is it possible to apply $LDL$ decomposition and then state that A is positive definite if $D$ is positive definite ?
Since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, it would be easy to check its eigenvalues, and hence, positive definiteness.

Yes: $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle LDL^\ast x,x\rangle=\langle DL^\ast x,L^\ast x\rangle=\langle Du,u\rangle$ (where $u=L^\ast x$ is arbitrary since $L$ is invertible), so $A$ has the same spectrum hence same signature as $D$.

This holds true in general ? I mean would $LDL$ decomposition definitely produce a diagonal matrix $D$ ? Are there any cases, where $LDL$ would fail ?
